# MySQL: problem to build multiple mysql select

Tags: mysql

i have a problem to build multiple mysql select. I am a german guy, i hope my english is enough to explain. I know already, that this:

```
$mysqli->prepare("
SELECT gender
     , age
     , education
     , department
     , code_numbers
  FROM ".TABLE_ANSWERS_BASIC_SELECT." 
WHERE gender = 'female' 
   AND gender = 'male'
")
```

not work.

How i can do this? I need to create the WHERE with checkboxes, so the WHERE is on the fly.

I did read a lot answer here about this, but nothing works for me.
Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Maybe you will find your answer here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php I assume you need to work with parameters, so that your WHERE statement only selects Male or Female

Comment: Even in this topsy turvy world gender cannot be simultaneously one thing and another thing. Perhaps you meant 'or'. And if you're still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gender = 'female' and gender = 'male'` means you want the ones who are male and female at the same time. `OR` is the keyword you're looking for. Replace your condition by this one : `gender = 'female' or gender = 'male'`

Comment: Then he will still get all the people who are male or female. I think he wants to only get the gender Male or Female, but not at the same time. depending on what the value is in the checkbox

Comment: There may be other genders in his table, or eventually *not specified*

Comment: if male and femal select the MySQL query should gave me both

Comment: @Cid Thank you very much! This works with all the values in my array.